# Sencha Touch, an iframe is shown when selectfield is opened

Tags: css, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.3

I've got a problem when changing the `selectfield` item in Sencha Touch 2.3.0. As shown in the picture below, I got a "blue screen" whenever I try to drag the `selectfield` item to change its value.

[image: app layout]

When I used the inspect-element on Chrome, I realized that it is an iframe.

So I tried to "remove" the iframe by setting it in the CSS

```
iframe {
    display: none !important;
}
```

on top of `index.html` but it didn't work. so I tried another method in CSS

```
iframe {
    visibility:hidden !important;
    width: 0px !important;
    height: 0px !important;
}
```

and it still didn't work, the blue screen is still there. How can I remove this iframe?

Comment: How did you define the form and the picker?

Comment: I didn't define it. Should I define it?